# Database deletion aborted

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, fast-sync, removedb

I'm using the command line to delete the existing chaindata so I can fast sync:

```
geth removedb
```

But I am returned with:

```
Database deletion aborted
Database doesn't exist, skipping
```

So then I run:

```
geth --fast
```

And I'm returned:

```
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: leveldb/storage: corrupted or incomplete meta file
```

I repeat the removedb command under the assumption that whatever chaindata is there is corrupted. But then it tells me nothing is there. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try this: 
- go to your ethereum folder (e.g. "~/.ethereum/")
- go in "geth/chaindata". 
If this folder is empty, then there is no database file
and I don't know where meta files are.
If there is something, delete it.

Anyway, note that geth --fast is deprecated.
You should use geth --syncmode "fast" instead.